# IE fails once again, jQuery scroll vibrating heavily

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, scroll

I'm using jQuery's scrollTop and scrollLeft to scroll on a website. Everything works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE9 the screen vibrates like crazy when scrolling.

This is my code for scrolling:

```
$('body').animate({
    scrollTop: '1980px',
    scrollLeft: '500px'
}, 800, 'swing');
```

I've also tried using animate on $(window), $('html') and $('html, body'), no effect.

You can view the live website here: [webvalid.nl/thomas](http://www.webvalid.nl/thomas)

Has anyone had similar problems? I couldn't anything googling... Thanks in advance!

Comment: It actually "vibrates" as well in Safari 5 on OS X for certain transitions. My best guess without looking at the code would be, that these transitions use "competing" animations. E.g. page scrolls left, circle animates right.

Comment: They always more or less move in the same way, but yes, at different speeds. I also suspected it might be because IE can't compute the diagonal movement (because it's moving both horizontally and vertically)? Do you have any idea on how to get closer to a fix?

Comment: A possible solution might be to first scroll and then animate the circles. Would that work?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue.  Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the solution you are looking for but you could always use:
http://www.dyn-web.com/code/scroll/

I thought this might work because there is no easing, and it looks to me this could be done by scrolling a div and doing the animation separately on the left.

sorry if im no help...